# What is this strange structure, of a type often seen by pilots in hilly regions?

Tags: military, flight-training, mountain-flying

I spotted a strange structure near a few paragliding spots in italian Alps. It's a screen about 10 meters wide, 6 meters tall, mounted on concrete base on ridge top. Someone said it's a training target for fighter jets, is it true? If so, is it targeted with real ammo or some kind of video-based training system?

Pictured: Monte Dolada, [46°11'34.68"N, 12°20'25.41"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/46%C2%B011'34.7%22N+12%C2%B020'25.4%22E/@46.1929667,12.3398311,280m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d46.1929667!4d12.3403917)

[image: Strange structure in italian Alps]

[image: Strange structure in italian Alps]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a reflector for microwave links, a [passive repeater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_repeater).

More info here *(article in Spanish)*: http://notascordobesas.blogspot.com/2015/01/el-repetidor-pasivo-de-microondas.html